# Batch Script - How to pause (Press any key to continue . . .) on error?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like my script to execute the `pause` command whether the script completes, or if an error/exception if thrown.

Basically, I want the script to behave as if I placed

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM Keep cmd window open until script finishes in case of error
if not defined in_subprocess (cmd /k set in_subprocess=y ^& %0 %*) & exit )
```

at the top of the script, but give the **Press any key to continue . . .** option to exit/close the cmd window.

Comment: The cmd.exe window should always remain open until the script exits/completes. So logically, you would very likely be able to check the ErrorLevel from that last command, and pause it if it is not `0`. e.g. `If ErrorLevel 1 Pause`, `If %ErrorLevel% Equ 1 Pause`, `If Not "%ErrorLevel%" == "0" Pause`. You also have the option of changing `Pause` to `timeout -1` too!

Comment: `command || pause`, for example `ping localhost || pause` and `ping nonsense || pause`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Here is what I ended up with for general use:

```
@echo off

REM ##########################################################################################################
REM  Functions
REM ##########################################################################################################
goto :main

REM ##########################################################################################################
REM  run_and_keep_window_open_with_press_key_to_close_window
REM ##########################################################################################################
:run_and_keep_window_open_with_press_key_to_close_window

    echo "hi there"
    sfgsdgfdfg

goto :eof

REM ##########################################################################################################
REM  Main
REM ##########################################################################################################
:main

call :run_and_keep_window_open_with_press_key_to_close_window
if %errorlevel% EQU 0 (pause) else (color CF && pause)
```